# socket.gaierror: [Errno -2]

Tags: mqtt

Here is my code on the bottom is the ERROR:

This is my config file:

```
[MQTT]
userMQTT = /
passwdMQTT = /
hostMQTT = broker.hivemq.com
poerMQTT = 1883
```

Above is mine config file where i used public broker. And now the rest of the code:

```
import configparser
from time import localtime, strftime
import json
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('/home/pi/bin/py.conf')     # Broker connection config.


requestTopic  = 'services/timeservice/request/+'        # Request comes in 
here. Note wildcard.
responseTopic = 'services/timeservice/response/'        # Response goes 
here. Request ID will be appended later

def onConnect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
   print("Connected with result code " + str(rc))

def onMessage(client, userdata, message):
   requestTopic = message.topic
   requestID = requestTopic.split('/')[3]       # obtain requestID as last 
field from the topic

   print("Received a time request on topic " + requestTopic + ".")

   lTime = strftime('%H:%M:%S', localtime())

   client.publish((responseTopic + requestID), payload=lTime, qos=0, 
retain=False)

def onDisconnect(client, userdata, message):
    print("Disconnected from the broker.")


# Create MQTT client instance
mqttc = mqtt.Client(client_id='raspberrypi', clean_session=True)

mqttc.on_connect = onConnect
mqttc.on_message = onMessage
mqttc.on_disconnect = onDisconnect

# Connect to the broker
mqttc.username_pw_set(config['MQTT']['userMQTT'], password=config['MQTT'] 
   ['passwdMQTT'])
```

BUT after i type:

```
mqttc.connect(config['MQTT']['hostMQTT'], port=int(config['MQTT'] 
['portMQTT']), keepalive=60, bind_address="")
```

I get an ERROR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 
768, in connect
    return self.reconnect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 
895, in reconnect
    sock = socket.create_connection((self._host, self._port), source_address= 
(self._bind_address, 0))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 694, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 733, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

I tried putting an address in bind_address="" but i keep getting the same ERROR. I tried putting bind_address="0.0.0.0" or my local address.

Comment: The error is to do with the port number not the `bind_address` (which you can just remove and it will default to something sensible)

Comment: Edit the question to include the config file so we can see exactly what you have

Comment: I edited so it's more clear what is in my config file, you were right, before it was hard to separate the code from the config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your config file contains:

```
poerMQTT = 1883
```

Where as your code is accessing:

```
portMQTT
```